# Filter function in Spark

Tags: scala, dictionary, filter, apache-spark, rdd

I have the following code written in scala in Spark:

(inactiveIDs is a `RDD[(Int, Seq[String])]`, persons is a `Broadcast[RDD[(Int, Seq[Event])]]` and Event is a class that I have created)

```
val test = persons.value
  .map{tuple => (tuple._1, tuple._2
  .filter{event => inactiveIDs.filter(event2 => event2._1 == tuple._1).count() != 0})}
```

and the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide more information about the problem and the way persons is handled.

Comment: Paste the full stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I can't filter a rdd inside another filter